# Utility type for extensions?

Tags: typescript, type-alias

Is there a way to alias the type `B extends { parents: Set<B> }` below?

```js
export interface Dag<B extends { parents: Set<B> }> {
  root: B;
  tips: Set<B>;
  blocks: Set<B>;

  // The reverse of the dag
  childMap: WeakMap<B, Set<B>>;
}
```

I tried

```js
type DagBlock<B> = B extends { parents: Set<B> };
```

but I get the error `Exported type alias 'DagBlock' has or is using private name ''.`

Comment: [Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) aren't types, so you can't use a type alias for them.  Does `type Block<B>={parents: Set<B>}` and then `interface Dag<B extends Block<B>>` as in [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na0EEw) work for you?  If not,  can you elaborate on the use case?

Comment: Add your comment an answer and I'll accept it.